# Displaying browser information using javascript in YUI Dialog

Tags: dialog, yui

I'm creating a YUI dialog and using it to call a a JSP which contains various  tags with 'document.write' to display client/browser diagnostics like java enable, applet enabled etc.

I have also used YAHOO.plugin.Dispatcher to process the JSP result but the scripts to display the information doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's enough information here to totally solve your problem, but at a high level it seems like you might be better served making a Connection Manager or Get call to the server and have the JSP page return a JSON object with the metadata; then you can write a quick script to process that data and display it.

Here's an example that covers the rudiments of that approach:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/get/get-script-simple.html